# How APK is executed in an Emulator without signing?

Tags: android, android-emulator, apk, code-signing

Recently I attended an interview, where interviewer asked below question:

**I hope you know APKs must be signed before release. But while using emulator to run/test the application, we are not signing the application. Why is that? And how does the application installs successfully without any warning and executes it successfully?**

I said something, but I know it is not the correct justification.

Googled, but couldn't find a proper justification/explanation.

Can anyone provide some references or explanation?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html.

Comment: Those are signed by debug key of android. See details `Signing in Debug Mode` section of the link as raghu has given

Comment: also check this para 2 http://developer.android.com/tools/building/index.html

Comment: @Raghu: Thanks. Doubt cleared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To test and debug your application, the build tools sign your application with a special debug key that is created by the Android SDK build tools.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, there are 2 types of Keystore:

1. debug.keystore
2. Keystore created by user, which requires to sign app while releasing/uploading on play store.

So while developing android apps, you are using debug.keystore by default, it doesn't matter whether you are testing app on emulator or real device.